# How to ask an edit reviewer questions about his review of my edit?

Tags: support, editing

my edit suggestion was rejected by someone, and I would like to ask him/her to tell me more specific reasons. How can I do that?

Comment: Ping him on chat, or post the link to the specific review here.

Comment: You're welcome to contact them through chat, but your edit looks good, and considering it was approved anyway, I would say the person who rejected it was wrong

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: It seems like my edit was rejected, because the question itself was not a good question, and my edit did not make the question better. Thanks.

Comment: @muru: Unfortunately there are almost no people in the chat... :-/